# print output of a function in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, function, printing

```
Public Function random_key(ByVal lenght As Integer) As String
    Randomize()
    Dim s As New System.Text.StringBuilder("")
    Dim b() As Char = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".ToCharArray()
    For i As Integer = 1 To lenght
        Randomize()
        Dim z As Integer = Int(((b.Length - 2) - 0 + 1) * Rnd()) + 1
        s.Append(b(z))
    Next
    Return s.ToString
    Console.WriteLine(s.ToString)

End Function
```

i wanna print it like 
s=textbox1.text or somethhing...

Comment: Visual Studios should have given a warning for that code being unreachable.

Comment: @Yatrix: In VS 2010 still not in VB.NET.

Answer (score 1):

What wrong with using [`Console.WriteLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.writeline.aspx)?

Note that you should not put it behind the [`return` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e34641s%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in the method because code behind a return is [unreachable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c26da40e%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

```
Dim random As String = random_key(10)
Console.WriteLine(random)
```